# Ways of picking 5 elements from a set of non-distinct elements

Tags: probability, combinatorics

The problem i have in mind is the following:

I have a bag of M&Ms containing 29 blue ones, 26 brown ones, 16 yellow ones, 19 green ones, 15 orange ones and 21 red ones.

I draw 5 of them from the bag and I'd like to know the probability of picking exactly 1 blue one, 1 yellow one, 1 green one, 1 orange one and 1 red one.

My main doubt comes from computing the number of different ways i can pick 5 elements from the bag: C(N 5), where N is the total number of M&Ms, isn't taking in consideration the fact that the same color elements are indistinguishable from one another

Comment: I think you don't want to take into consideration that same color elements are indistinguishable. The more, say, blue ones there are, the more ways there are of choosing lots of blue ones instead of getting one of each of five specified colors.

Comment: I agree, indistinguishability is not relevant. You can mark M&M's by numbers and make distinguishable, without affecting the problem.

Comment: @GerryMyerson as a counter example, let's say i have 3 white balls and 2 black balls and i want to pick 3 of them (order doesn't matter as in the M&M's case).
The possible ways to pick them would be C(5, 3) = 10, but intuitively i can either have 3 white balls, 2 white balls and 1 black ball or 2 black balls and 1 white ball: 3 cases and not 10

Comment: @Riccardo Given M&M's are not quantum particles, distinguishabilty/indistinguisablity is not relevant.

Comment: But, Riccardo, those three cases are not equally likely, so you won't be able to use that approach to calculate any probabilities.

Comment: Do you understand my comment, Riccardo? Do you understand the answer that was posted two days ago?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP is missing in action.

Comment: @GerryMyerson sorry for the late answer. I understood your answer: i don't know why but i wasn't considering that the three cases in my example weren't equally likely! Now everything makes more sense, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Total M&Ms:
$$Total \:M\&Ms = 29 blue + 26 brown + 16 yellow + 19 green + 15 orange + 21 red$$

Total outcomes:
$$Total,outcomes = C(126, 5) = \binom{126}{5}$$

Successful outcomes:
$$Successful,outcomes = C(29, 1) \times C(16, 1) \times C(19, 1) \times C(15, 1) \times C(21, 1)$$
$$Successful,outcomes = \binom{29}{1} \times \binom{16}{1} \times \binom{19}{1} \times \binom{15}{1} \times \binom{21}{1}$$

Probability of the event:
$$P(event) = \frac{Successful,outcomes}{Total,outcomes}$$
$$P(event) = \frac{\binom{29}{1} \times \binom{16}{1} \times \binom{19}{1} \times \binom{15}{1} \times \binom{21}{1}}{\binom{126}{5}}$$

Plugging in the values and computing the probability:
$P(event) = \frac{4331340}{104240244}$